# UIButton not responsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a UIButton programmatically an added a function to it. It doesn't respond during runtime.

```
    scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 300, 40);
    loginBut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    loginBut.frame = scrollViewFrame;
    loginBut.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    loginBut.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:33];
    [loginBut setTitleColor:[UIColor Gray] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginBut setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loginBut setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];

    [loginBut addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(checkError)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.loginBut = loginBut;

    [self.view addSubview:loginBut];
```

The action:

```
- (void)checkError {
    if ([dispName.text isEqualToString:@""]&&[pw.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alertFailed = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"\nError" message:@"1. Display Name missing.\n2. Password missing." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertFailed show];
    }

}
```

Thanx in advance...

Comment: have you tried NSLog(...) in your `checkError` to see if it's getting called?

Comment: How does [UIColor Gray] compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a NSLog() inside the  `- (void)checkError`  method. If it printed, then some thing went wrong with your `if` condition.

else just try,

```
 [self.view bringSubViewToFront:loginBut];
 loginBut.userIntractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ([dispName.text isEqualToString:@""]&&[pw.text isEqualToString:@""])

Perhaps those tests are just failing. For example, maybe `dispName.text` is nil. That is not the same as being equal to the empty string.

Comment: The idea is if nobody key in anything to the dispName and pw textfield, it will prompt an alert. i guess its not 'isEqualToString'? What should it be?

Comment: Why don't you use NSLog or pause in the debugger to examine what their values are at the moment? You don't seem to be doing any testing, logging, or debugging. You do not have to *guess* what your code is doing, you know! And you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

to see if the button is responding first add

```
NSLog("checkError");
```

before the if statement to the method

```
- (void)checkError;
```